# Solving a nonlinear equation numerically for all multiple solutions

Tags: python, optimization, solver, scipy-optimize

I have a nonlinear equation: I plot the left-hand and right-hand sides of this equation in the picture below. Evidently there are two solutions. I have tried scipy.optimize.fsolve and guess the starting points strategically to find the two solutions but this is quite non-robust. Are there a Python solver that can just find all the solutions to this equation, e.g. within some finite set of x-values?

[Function with multiple solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Ysi.png)

Comment: @nutix  could you post the equations?

Comment: In higher dimensions, we could use a global solver. Add the constraint `||x-sol||>=tol` to find a new solution. (Warning: this constraint is non-convex). The global solver Baron includes an option `NumSols` so you can tell how many solutions it should look for,

Answer (score 1):

The solver doesn't know how many solutions there are, or where they may occur, so you'll need to search for the solutions. One way to do that is:

- Solve the model to find a solution. Let's say it occurs at x = 88.7.
- Add a constraint that excludes that solution by a very small amount. e.g. x <= 88.7 - 0.00001.
- Solve again. The solver will either find the other solution or say that there aren't any feasible solutions.
- Because we don't know which solution the solver will find the first time, we also need to check the other direction. e.g. x >= 88.7 + 0.00001
- If there are potentially more than two solutions, you'll need to repeat this process, progressively sub-dividing the solution space until there are no more solutions.